# Find elements of a list that contain substrings from another list in Python

Tags: python, list

In my code, I have two lists, of different lenghts, which I'll call "main" and "secondary". I need to use elements in secondary to select elements in main. However, secondary contains elements that are just sub-sets of the strings in main. In code:

```
main = ["pinecone", "treeleaf", "dishwasher"]
secondary = ["pine", "washer", "unrelated", "flowerbed"]
```

Usually secondary is much longer than main (I mention this in case solutions involve performance penalties). 
How do I go and select elements in "main" basing on "secondary" with the most efficient (and Pythonic) way possible? If it were a function, I'd expect

```
>>> selected_items = select_items(main, secondary)
>>> print selected_items
["pinecone", "dishwasher"]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Naive approach:

```
In [2]: main = ["pinecone", "treeleaf", "dishwasher"]

In [3]: secondary = ["pine", "washer", "unrelated", "flowerbed"]

In [4]: [x for x in main if any(x in y or y in x for y in secondary)]
Out[4]: [u'pinecone', u'dishwasher']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def select_items(strings, substrs):
    return [m for m in strings if any(s in m for s in substrs)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach works when your main list and secondary list are the same:

```
In [2]: main = ["pinecone", "treeleaf", "dishwasher"] + ["pine", "washer", "unrelated", "flowerbed"]

In [4]: [x for x in main for y in main if y in x and x != y]
Out[4]: ['pinecone', 'dishwasher']
```

Note, you can get the partially matching string instead (or even both!):

```
In [5]: [y for x in main for y in main if y in x and x != y]
Out[5]: ['pine', 'washer']

In [6]: [(y,x) for x in main for y in main if y in x and x != y]
Out[6]: [('pine', 'pinecone'), ('washer', 'dishwasher')]
```