# get list of elements that don't contain elements in another list

Tags: python

I have the following two lists, one which i want to extract from, and the other is a list that elements from the first list should **not** contain
as following:

```
exclude_list = ['not_use', 'dont_use']

feature_list = ['good_use', 'very_good_use', 'hey_not_use', 'hey_dont_use']

desired_list = ['good_use', 'very_good_use']

ret_list = [x for x in feature_list if any(x not in y for y in exclude_list)]

print(ret_list)

assert set(ret_list) == set(desired_list), 'list are not identical'
```

I tried looking in question such as:

[Find elements of a list that contain substrings from another list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828636/find-elements-of-a-list-that-contain-substrings-from-another-list-in-python)

But for some kind of reason this one seems to be tricky.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
[x for x in feature_list if not any(y in x for y in exclude_list)]
# ['good_use', 'very_good_use']
```

Note that the `not` has to have scope *over* the `any` (not the other way round) and that it is `y in x`, not `x in y`.